# T-SQL How to SELECT records with DATETIME = Weekends and Weekdays after hours

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with a `DATETIME` column called `[Date]`. I need to select only records that have the `[Date]` column = Sunday and Saturday, and also Monday through Friday from 12:00am till 8:00am and 5:00pm till 12:00am.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (DATEPART(weekday, [Date]) IN (1, 7)
       OR (DATEPART(weekday, [Date]) IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
           AND (CAST([Date] AS TIME) BETWEEN '12:00am'
                                     AND     '8:00am'
                OR CAST([Date] AS TIME) BETWEEN '5:00pm'
                                        AND     '12:00:00am')))
```

When I check the results, I find that it is missing some records in the table which have the [Date] in the "after hours". What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you show a few rows that are missing?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes formatting your code can help you see the logical (and/or) groupings better.

```
WHERE 

(DATEPART(weekday, [Date]) IN (1, 7)) --<-- Put an extra closing paren here to isolate this side of the disjunctive (OR)

OR

(
   DATEPART(weekday, [Date]) IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
   AND (
          (CAST([Date] AS TIME) BETWEEN '12:00am' AND '8:00am') --<--the first and last paren are not necessary, but help you to visually isolate this side of the disjunctive (OR)
          OR 
          (CAST([Date] AS TIME) BETWEEN '5:00pm' AND '12:00:00am') --<-- same here
       )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I changed the last '12:00:00am' to '11:59:59pm'.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: For cleaner/simpler code you can replace "between" conditions with comparisons: `CAST([Date] AS TIME) <= '8:00am' or CAST([Date] AS TIME) >= '5:00pm'`